# Handle Entites in xml document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

In my source some entities are encountered

**Source xml**

```
<name>&#145; &amp;#145; &amp;</name>
```

**Expected output**

```
<name>&#145; &#145; &amp;</name>
```

i tried with character-map but it is not convert as expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a template to process all nodes as text and replace it with tokenize value **

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches(., '&amp;#')">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;#([0-9]+);', concat('&#38;', '#$1;'))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but It impact speed of my conversion because I have very large file, but it will work.